# Ubuntu Distribution: Original Investor

Tags: canonical

I just have seen a "Canonical Limited" is the investor of Ubuntu Linux.

First time I downloaded Ubuntu Linux a US Corporation was an investor of Ubuntu.

Sameways many different guesses about why it has an African word as the name of the distribution came up in new forums about Ubuntu Linux.

As Ubuntu started, it's name was just an African word to turn the common mind in the world of Linux geeks, as most where against asking questions of beginners and answered "use google" or "read the manual (rtfm)" - so creators of Ubuntu used an African word of humanity that it will have several bulletin boards that will not "harm", if a beginner has a frequently asked question.
This is how I do know it from the beginning of Ubuntu Linux. Actually some other boards started and even Wikipedia has a different mind of Ubuntu, since Canonical took over.

So what US Corporation was it in the very beginning?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, as [Mark Shuttleworth](https://launchpad.net/~sabdfl) is the "original investor" and he is a person, not a US Corporation. (Also, [Shuttleworth is South African](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth)--he is not from the United States.)

Comment: You can do betrer: he's from South Africa, has been to space as the 1st African. Canonical is based in England... ;) and his African roots is 1 of the pilars why Ubuntu is free. It is his attemp to bring an OS into Africa.

Comment: hm yeah you're right... maybe I was just confused and did not had it right in mind

Answer (score 2):

Quite a lot of information and on the background on Ubuntu can be found on the respective pages:

- [About Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu)
- [About Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical)

The idea and the spirit behind Ubuntu, and why this name was chosen can be read from there (without much we could add to this):

> Ubuntu is an ancient African word meaning 'humanity to others'. It also means 'I am what I am because of who we all are'. The Ubuntu operating system brings the spirit of Ubuntu to the world of computers.